# Access consent info from Individual Object

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, getobjectinfo

I am trying to grab the consent fields on the Individual Object (The actual object called Individual).
Here is my code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import INDIVIDUAL from "@salesforce/schema/Individual";

export default class IndividualConsent extends LightningElement {

  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectAiName: INDIVIDUAL })
  objectInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

However, no data is being returned.
If I use the same @wire and import methods to get the data for Account, it works:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import ACCOUNT_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Account";

export default class AccountName extends LightningElement {

  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectAiName: ACCOUNT_NAME })
  objectInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is so? I have never used the Individual Object before, so I am a bit lost as to why it is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your syntax: replace `objectAiName` with `objectApiName`.